# How to print(C code) only the XML tags by skipping all the values in between the tags?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Here my requirement is to skip all values between the tags and printing the same, i tried it in brute force way but still not getting, anyone please suggest.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char str1[50] = {"<a>1</a><b>2</b><c>3</c>"};
    char str2[20];
    int i;
    i = 0;

    while(str1[i] !='\0')
    {
        if(str1[i] == '<' || str1[i] >= 'A' && str1[i] <='Z' || str1[i] >= 'a' && str1[i] <='z')
        {
            str2[i] = str1[i];
        }
        i++;
        printf("%s",str2);
    }
}
```

Actual output: `<<a<a<a<a<a<a<a<a<a<a<a<a<a<a<a<a<a<a<a<a<a<a<a`

Expected output: `<a></a><b></b><c></c>`

Comment: I suggest learning some basics of formal language theory.

Comment: One other gotcha you need to be aware of - strings in C need to be terminated with a NUL (`'\0'`) character otherwise you'll experience all manner of fun undefined behaviour. It needs something akin to `str2[i] = '\0';` before you can use it, like with `printf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with your code is that you use `i` for writing into `str2`. However, as you don't want to write all characters from `str1` into `str2` you need two index-variables, i.e. one for reading and another for writing.

A very simple approach for your task is to look for `'<'` and then copy all following characters until you see a `'>'`. That could look like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char str1[50] = {"<a>1</a><b>2</b><c>3</c>"};
    char str2[50] = { 0 };
    int i, j;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    while(str1[i] !='\0')
    {
      if(str1[i] == '<')
      {
        // Found tag
        // Now copy all characters to str2 until end-of-tag is found
        do
        {
          str2[j++] = str1[i++];
          if (str1[i] =='\0') exit(1); // Unexpected format.. terminate
        } while (str1[i] != '>');
        str2[j++] = str1[i];           // Also copy the '>'
      }
      ++i;
    }
    printf("%s\n",str2);
}
```

However, notice that parsing (user) input is a pretty complicated task because you need to handle all sort of errors in the input. The code above has (nearly) no error check and is therefore not useful for passing real (user) input. The code only handles "well formed" input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to improve your code:

- First of all include in parenthesis the two pair AND conditions,
- Forgot to include in if statement the slash(/) and the greater
  character(>)
- You will gonna need a second int variable for indexing the str2 array
- The printf be outside of while.

Also is good to initialize the str2 with 0 values. See memset.

Answer (score 0):

**Kindly note it does not cover all test cases scenarios.**

My code have some code writing standard issues, but I made as minimal changes as possible so that you can understand the changes made.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char str1[50] = {"<a>1</a><b>2</b><c>3</c>"};
    char str2[20];
    int i,j;
    i = 0,j = 0;

    while(str1[i] !='\0') {
        if(str1[i] == '<' ){
            do {
                str2[j] = str1[i];
                i++;
                j++;

             }while( str1[i] >= 'A' && str1[i] <='Z' || str1[i] >= 'a' && str1[i] <='z' || str1[i] == '/');

             if(str1[i] == '>' ){
                str2[j] = str1[i];
                i++;
                j++;
                continue;
             }
             else {
                //todo error condition
             }
        }
        i++;
    }
    str2[j] = '\0';
    printf("%s",str2);

}
```